# How to use a Llama model with langchain? It gives an error: Pipeline cannot infer suitable model classes from: <model_name> - HuggingFace

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, langchain, chromadb, large-language-model

finetuned a model (https://huggingface.co/decapoda-research/llama-7b-hf) using peft and lora and saved as https://huggingface.co/lucas0/empath-llama-7b. Now im getting `Pipeline cannot infer suitable model classes from` when trying to use it along with with langchain and chroma vectordb:

```
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceHubEmbeddings
from langchain import PromptTemplate, HuggingFaceHub, LLMChain
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

repo_id = "sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2"
embedder = HuggingFaceHubEmbeddings(
    repo_id=repo_id,
    task="feature-extraction",
    huggingfacehub_api_token="XXXXX",
)
comments = ["foo", "bar"]
embeddings = embedder.embed_documents(texts=comments)
docsearch = Chroma.from_texts(comments, embedder).as_retriever()
#docsearch = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings)

llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id='lucas0/empath-llama-7b', huggingfacehub_api_token='XXXXX')
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=docsearch, return_source_documents=False)

q = input("input your query:")
result = qa.run(query=q)

print(result["result"])
```

is anyone able to tell me how to fix this? Is it an issue with the model card? I was facing issues with the lack of the config.json file and ended up just placing the same config.json as the model I used as base for the lora fine-tuning. Could that be the origin of the issue? If so, how to generate the correct config.json without having to get the original llama weights?

Also, is there a way of loading several sentences into a custom HF model (not only OpenAi, as the [tutorial](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/indexes/vectorstores/examples/chroma.html) show) without using vector dbs?

Thanks!

---

The same issue happens when trying to run the API on the model's HF page:

[image]

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of the error `Pipeline cannot infer suitable model classes from when trying to use it along with with langchain and chroma vectordb:` so that it can help us help you better.

Comment: It'll also be helpful to post the link of the tutorial you're referring to at the end of the question to give more context.

Comment: One last bit of information needed to understand how to help you to debug the issue, how was `lucas0/empath-llama-7b` saved? Did you use `model.save_pretrained()`

Comment: @alvas no, I've used `model.push_to_hub(...)`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vx0Mzch6 this is the full stacktrace

Comment: Let me know if the answer needs more clarification. Have fun with the peft model!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before using the `langchain` API to the huggingface model, you should try to load the model in Huggingface:

```
from transformers import AutoModel

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('lucas0/empath-llama-7b')
```

And that'll throw some errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1b9ce76f5421> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 from transformers import AutoModel
      2 
----> 3 model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('lucas0/empath-llama-7b')

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
   2553                             )
   2554                         else:
-> 2555                             raise EnvironmentError(
   2556                                 f"{pretrained_model_name_or_path} does not appear to have a file named"
   2557                                 f" {_add_variant(WEIGHTS_NAME, variant)}, {TF2_WEIGHTS_NAME}, {TF_WEIGHTS_NAME} or"

OSError: lucas0/empath-llama-7b does not appear to have a file named pytorch_model.bin, tf_model.h5, model.ckpt or flax_model.msgpack.
```

Then looking into the model files, it looks like only the adapter model is saved and not the model, https://huggingface.co/lucas0/empath-llama-7b/tree/main, so the Automodel is throwing tantrums.

To load an adapted model, you have to the base model and the peft (adapter model separated, first the installs (restart after installs, if needed):

```
! pip install -U peft accelerate
! pip install -U sentencepiece
! pip install -U transformers
```

Then to load the model, take a look at the `guanaco` example, [Trying to install guanaco (pip install guanaco) for a text classification model but getting error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76372007/610569) (You will need a GPU runtime)

```
import torch
from peft import PeftModel    
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, LlamaTokenizer, StoppingCriteria, StoppingCriteriaList, TextIteratorStreamer

model_name = "decapoda-research/llama-7b-hf"
adapters_name = 'lucas0/empath-llama-7b'

print(f"Starting to load the model {model_name} into memory")

m = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_name,
    #load_in_4bit=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    device_map={"": 0}
)
m = PeftModel.from_pretrained(m, adapters_name)
m = m.merge_and_unload()
tok = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
tok.bos_token_id = 1

stop_token_ids = [0]

print(f"Successfully loaded the model {model_name} into memory")
```

---

Now you can load the model that you've adapted/fine-tuned in Huggingface `transformers`, you can try it with `langchain`, before that we have to dig the langchain code, to use a prompt with HF model, users are told to do this:

```
from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain, HuggingFaceHub

template = """ Hey llama, you like to eat quinoa. Whatever question I ask you, you reply with "Waffles, waffles, waffles!".
 Question: {input} Answer: """
prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["input"])


model = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id="facebook/mbart-large-50",
                       model_kwargs={"temperature": 0, "max_length":200},
chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=model)
```

But when we look at the `HuggingFaceHub` object it isn't just a vanilla `AutoModel` from transformers huggingface.

When we look at https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/master/langchain/chains/llm.py, we see that it's trying to load the `llm=...` argument with some wrapper class, so we dig deeper into langchain's `HuggingFaceHub` object at https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/master/langchain/llms/huggingface_hub.py

The `HuggingFaceHub` object wraps over the `huggingface_hub.inference_api.InferenceApi` for the `text-generation`, `text2text-generation` or `summarization` tasks

And `HuggingFaceHub` looks like some spaghetti like object that inherits from `LLM` object https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/master/langchain/llms/base.py#L453

To summarize this a little, we want to:

- load a `HuggingFaceHub` with `langchain` API,
- and the `HuggingFaceHub` is actually a wrapper over the `huggingface_hub.inference_api.InferenceApi`
- and the `HuggingFaceHub` object is a subclass of `llm.base.LLM`

---

Given that knowledge on the `HuggingFaceHub` object, now, we have several options:

**Opinion:** The easiest way around it is to totally avoid `langchain`, since it's wrapper around things, you can write your customized wrapper that skip the levels of inheritance created in langchain to wrap around as many tools as it can/need

**Ideally:** Ask the `langchain` developer/maintainer to load peft/adapter model and write another subclass for them

**Practical:*** Lets hack the thing and write our own `LLM` subclass.

---

**Practical solution:**

Lets try to hack up a new `LLM` subclass

```
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Mapping, Optional

from pydantic import Extra, root_validator

from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManagerForLLMRun
from langchain.llms.base import LLM
from langchain.llms.utils import enforce_stop_tokens

from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain

class HuggingFaceHugs(LLM):
  pipeline: Any
  class Config:
    """Configuration for this pydantic object."""
    extra = Extra.forbid

  def __init__(self, model, tokenizer, task="text-generation"):
    super().__init__()
    self.pipeline = pipeline(task, model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

  @property
  def _llm_type(self) -> str:
    """Return type of llm."""
    return "huggingface_hub"

  def _call(self, prompt, stop: Optional[List[str]] = None, run_manager: Optional[CallbackManagerForLLMRun] = None,):
    # Runt the inference.
    text = self.pipeline(prompt, max_length=100)[0]['generated_text']
    
    # @alvas: I've totally no idea what this in langchain does, so I copied it verbatim.
    if stop is not None:
      # This is a bit hacky, but I can't figure out a better way to enforce
      # stop tokens when making calls to huggingface_hub.
      text = enforce_stop_tokens(text, stop)
    print(text)
    return text[len(prompt):]


template = """ Hey llama, you like to eat quinoa. Whatever question I ask you, you reply with "Waffles, waffles, waffles!".
 Question: {input} Answer: """
prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["input"])


hf_model = HuggingFaceHugs(model=m, tokenizer=tok)

chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=hf_model)

chain("Who is Princess Momo?")
```

Phew, `langchain` didn't complain... and here's the output:

```
{'input': 'Who is Princess Momo?',
 'text': ' She is a princess.  She is a princess.  She is a princess.  She is a princess.  She is a princess.  She is a princess.  She is a princess.  She is'}
```

**Epilogue**: Apparently this llama model doesn't understand that all it needs to do is to reply [`Waffles, waffles, waffles`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HOlXJ2EJxw&ab_channel=DC)

---

## TL;DR

See https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1l2GiSSPbajVyp2Nk3CFT4t3uH6-5TiBe?usp=sharing

Comment: To use the `RetrievalQA` instead of `LLMChain`, the idea is the same, create the `HuggingFaceHugs` and see if `RetrievalQA(llm=hf_model, chain_type="stuff", ...)` complains

Comment: Impressive! Thank you very much! One of the best answers I've seen in SO. I wanna be your fried! <3

Comment: One last detail: how to add the stop token to the end of the template?

Comment: Glad the answer helped!

Comment: As for the `enforce_stop_tokens` I think it's something unique to `langchain`, it'll be best to ask the developer/maintainer answer you on that. I'm not exactly why/how that's useful. I've put the details up for the question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76475527/how-does-enforce-stop-tokens-work-in-langchain-with-huggingface-models

Comment: I'm getting `CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1207.54 GiB (GPU 0; 14.62 GiB total capacity; 11.04 GiB already allocated; 2.79 GiB free; 11.32 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF` 1207 GBs, needed... theres something wrong. Ill create another question.