# How to load a fine-tuned peft/lora model based on llama with Huggingface transformers?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, llama-index, peft

I've followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Us5ZFp16PaU) tutorial ([colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14xo6sj4dARk8lXZbOifHEn1f_70qNAwy?usp=sharing#scrollTo=hsD1VKqeA62Z)) in order to finetune my model.

## Trying to load my locally saved model

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("finetuned_model")
```

yields `Killed`.

---

## Trying to load model from hub:

yields

```
import torch
from peft import PeftModel, PeftConfig
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

peft_model_id = "lucas0/empath-llama-7b"
config = PeftConfig.from_pretrained(peft_model_id)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(config.base_model_name_or_path, return_dict=True, load_in_8bit=True, device_map='auto')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(cwd+"/tokenizer.model")

# Load the Lora model
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, peft_model_id)
```

yields

```
AttributeError: /home/ubuntu/empath/lora/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/libbitsandbytes_cpu.so: undefined symbol: cget_col_row_stats
```

[full stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/g9x8G7A3)

## Model Creation:

I have finetuned a model using PEFT and LoRa:

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
"decapoda-research/llama-7b-hf",
torch_dtype=torch.float16,
device_map='auto',
)
```

I had to download and manually specify the llama tokenizer.

```
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer(cwd+"/tokenizer.model")
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
```

to the training:

```
from peft import LoraConfig, get_peft_model

config = LoraConfig(
    r=8,
    lora_alpha=16,
    target_modules=["q_proj", "k_proj", "v_proj", "o_proj"],
    lora_dropout=0.05,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM"
)

model = get_peft_model(model, config)

data = pd.read_csv("my_csv.csv")
dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(data)
tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(lambda samples: tokenizer(samples["text"]))

trainer = transformers.Trainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=tokenized_dataset,
    args=transformers.TrainingArguments(
        per_device_train_batch_size=4,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
        warmup_steps=100,
        max_steps=100,
        learning_rate=1e-3,
        fp16=True,
        logging_steps=1,
        output_dir='outputs',
    ),
    data_collator=transformers.DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer, mlm=False)
)
model.config.use_cache = True  # silence the warnings. Please re-enable for inference!
trainer.train()
```

and saved it locally with:

```
trainer.save_model(cwd+"/finetuned_model")
print("saved trainer locally")
```

as well as to the hub:

```
model.push_to_hub("lucas0/empath-llama-7b", create_pr=1)
```

How can I load my finetuned model?

Comment: `Killed` tends to mean you're running out of memory.

Comment: I understand that, but it sounds I bit illogical to me since I've trained the model and didn't run out of memory. Now I am just trying to load it...

Comment: Also, why can't the model be loaded from the hub?

Comment: You need a GPU runtime and most probably only A10g GPU on colab would run the 7B peft model.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To load a fine-tuned peft/lora model, take a look at the guanco example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76372390/610569

```
import torch
from peft import PeftModel    
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, LlamaTokenizer, StoppingCriteria, StoppingCriteriaList, TextIteratorStreamer

model_name = "decapoda-research/llama-7b-hf"
adapters_name = "lucas0/empath-llama-7b"

print(f"Starting to load the model {model_name} into memory")

m = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_name,
    #load_in_4bit=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    device_map={"": 0}
)
m = PeftModel.from_pretrained(m, adapters_name)
m = m.merge_and_unload()
tok = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
tok.bos_token_id = 1

stop_token_ids = [0]

print(f"Successfully loaded the model {model_name} into memory")
```

You will need an A10g GPU runtime minimally to load the model properly.

---

For more details see

- https://github.com/artidoro/qlora#tutorials-and-demonstrations
- **Inference notebook:** https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ge2F1QSK8Q7h0hn3YKuBCOAS0bK8E0wf?usp=sharing
- **Training notebook:** https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VoYNfYDKcKRQRor98Zbf2-9VQTtGJ24k?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, I had an error when load in 4bit is commented: "OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 86.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacty of 14.75 GiB of which 52.81 MiB is free". However,  when I uncommented I got: "ValueError: Cannot merge LORA layers when the model is loaded in 8-bit mode". Do I need to pass all my Qlora parameters?

Answer (score 3):

You can load like this after pushing. I did using the following snippet successfully .

```
# pip install peft transformers
import torch
from peft import PeftModel, PeftConfig
from transformers import LlamaTokenizer, LlamaForCausalLM
from accelerate import infer_auto_device_map, init_empty_weights

peft_model_id = "--path--"

config = PeftConfig.from_pretrained(peft_model_id)

model1 = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    config.base_model_name_or_path,
    torch_dtype='auto',
    device_map='auto',
    offload_folder="offload", offload_state_dict = True
)
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(config.base_model_name_or_path)

# Load the Lora model
model1 = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, peft_model_id)
```