# How to load LoRA weights saved locally?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-trainer

I am currently training a model and have saved the checkpoints for the LoRA adapters. I now have the .bin and .config file for the adapters. How do I reload everything for inference without pushing to huggingFace? Most of the documentation talks about pushing to huggingFace. I was not able to find anything regarding working with local files.

I tried
`lora_config = LoraConfig.from_pretrained('/path/to/adapter') model = get_peft_model(model, lora_config)`
But this did not work

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76459034/how-to-load-a-fine-tuned-peft-lora-model-based-on-llama-with-huggingface-transfo/76469875#76469875

Answer (score 0):

this may only create a peft model instead of loading LoRA weights, you can add a

```
from peft import load_peft_weights, set_peft_model_state_dict

lora_weights = load_peft_weights("/path/to/adapter")

set_peft_model_state_dict(model, adapter_weights)
```